# Flot - multiple axes - colors

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, flot

Is it possible in Flot to just color the side line of the axis instead of the tick labels and the grid?

I need something like this:
[JqPlot multi-axis example](http://jquery4php.sourceforge.net/index.php?section=components&module=jqPlot&method=multiple__Y__axes) (click on show demo)

Thanks!